# Question of dynamic memory allocation and dynamic memory deallocation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need someone to solve the problem which is a question of dynamic memory allocation and
dynamic deallocation.

Here's a part of code to create database

```
include <iostream>

#include <string>

    

using namespace std;

struct subject {        

    string subname;
    int score;
    string grade;
    float gpa;

};


struct student {        

    string stuname; 
    int stunum; 
    int subnum; 
    subject *sub;
    float avegpa = 0;

};


int main(void){
int i = 0; 

    cout << "Put number of students  : ";

    cin >> i;



    student* p = new student[i];
.
.
.
delete p->sub;
delete[] p;

return 0;
}
```

here's my desired result

1. Now, I have to enter the value of i first, but I hope I can automatically set
   the value of i.
2. In order to try number 1, I pushed back value of i and increased i, but there was an
   error. I don't know why.

This is the error message from number 2.

```
C++ crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer
```

Comment: depends on what happens between `student* p = new student[i]` and `delete p->sub`...

Comment: Just like you use `std::string` for strings, use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.

Comment: Almost certainly the program marched off the end of the array pointed at by `p`, but certainly did not do it in the given code. I suggest making a [mre], and if you still have a question when you're done, replace the code in the question.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that doesn't work? It seems like the code that doesn't work is just "..."

Comment: I can't see p->sub being initialised anywhere, so based on the code you provided, deleting that is undefined behaviour and may be the cause of your issue. However, as others have said, you need to include a minimal but complete example for people to be able to say more.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> delete p->sub;
> ```

You never initialised `p[0].sub`. Deleting (or even reading) an uninitialised pointer will result in undefined behaviour. You may `delete` only what you `new`.

P.S. Owning bare pointers are a bad idea. I recommend using `std::vector` to manage dynamic arrays.